# Facing an issue while installing ESim directly into android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, euiccmanager

Currently, i'm working on application which is related to eSIM installation by using direct method, i followed [Implementing eSIM](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview) provided example code but not succeeded yet.

i used TEST_SIM_PROFILE, TEST_SIM_PROFILE1 and TEST_SIM_PROFILE3 but it always return **0** in **onNewIntent(intent: Intent)**, so please check is there anything need to be add or improve into my code,

here is my Code

```
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.euicc.DownloadableSubscription
import android.telephony.euicc.EuiccManager
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TEST_SIM_PROFILE =
        "LPA:1\$MTAwMDAwMDAwMzQ2MzM5Y2E2NDgwNQ==$7UMyhYJKZLBfHZt2ve9vQH0oKvE=$"
    private val TEST_SIM_PROFILE1 =
        "1\$prod.smdp-plus.rsp.goog\$3TD6-8L82-HUE1-LVN6"
    private val TEST_SIM_PROFILE2 = "LPA:1\$lpa.airalo.com\$TEST"
    private val TEST_SIM_PROFILE3 = "dfdffdf"
    private val REQUEST_CODE_INSTALL = 1

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val esimButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.esimButton)
        esimButton.setOnClickListener { downloadTestProfile() }
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private fun downloadTestProfile() {
        val euiccManager = getSystemService(EUICC_SERVICE) as EuiccManager
        if (!euiccManager.isEnabled) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "eSIM is not supported on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }
        Log.d("eSIMInstall", "Attempting to install profile...");
        val subscription = DownloadableSubscription.forActivationCode(TEST_SIM_PROFILE)
        euiccManager.downloadSubscription(
            subscription, true, PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, REQUEST_CODE_INSTALL, Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.d("eSIMInstall", "on calling of newIntent...");
        val resultCode =
            intent.getIntExtra(EuiccManager.EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILED_CODE, 0)
        Log.d("eSIMResult", "Result code: $resultCode");

        when (resultCode) {
            EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_OK -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "eSIM profile installed successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()

            EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_RESOLVABLE_ERROR -> { }
            else -> Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to install eSIM profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
------------------------Manifest----------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTIONS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.EsimInstallation"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: as far as I remember, eSIM requires an Internet connection. Judging by your manifesto, you don't have this, because there is no permission for the Internet.
You also need to test this on a physical device that supports eSIM technology.

Comment: i added permission , but there is no change in result, it always returning *resultCode * is 0

Comment: i also tried [google test profile](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-test-profiles) but not working for me , if you have sample code or any working example code, might be helpful for me,

Comment: @AhmedRehman hi, any progress with that ? I am also trying to create Esim feature but euiccManager.isEnabled is always false. Can you help with that!

Comment: @AhmedRehman did you find any solution I am also stuck with this?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided looks mostly correct, but there are a few issues that need to be addressed. I've made the necessary corrections and improvements to your code to handle eSIM installation and results properly. Here's the corrected code in Kotlin:

```
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.euicc.DownloadableSubscription
import android.telephony.euicc.EuiccManager
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TEST_SIM_PROFILE =
        "LPA:1\$MTAwMDAwMDAwMzQ2MzM5Y2E2NDgwNQ==$7UMyhYJKZLBfHZt2ve9vQH0oKvE=$"
    private val REQUEST_CODE_INSTALL = 1

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val esimButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.esimButton)
        esimButton.setOnClickListener { downloadTestProfile() }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private fun downloadTestProfile() {
        val euiccManager = getSystemService(EUICC_SERVICE) as EuiccManager
        if (!euiccManager.isEnabled) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "eSIM is not supported on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }
        Log.d("eSIMInstall", "Attempting to install profile...")
        val subscription = DownloadableSubscription.forActivationCode(TEST_SIM_PROFILE)
        euiccManager.downloadSubscription(
            subscription,
            true,
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                REQUEST_CODE_INSTALL,
                Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.d("eSIMInstall", "on calling of newIntent...")
        val resultCode =
            intent.getIntExtra(EuiccManager.EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT, EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_ERROR)
        Log.d("eSIMResult", "Result code: $resultCode")

        when (resultCode) {
            EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_OK -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "eSIM profile installed successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()

            EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_RESOLVABLE_ERROR -> {
                // Handle resolvable error here if needed
            }
            else -> Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to install eSIM profile", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

I've made the following changes and improvements:

Changed the key for retrieving the result code from EuiccManager.EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILED_CODE to EuiccManager.EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT. This is the correct key for obtaining the result code.

Removed the TEST_SIM_PROFILE1, TEST_SIM_PROFILE2, and TEST_SIM_PROFILE3 variables as they were not used in your code.

Updated the handling of result codes to use EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_ERROR as the default value for resultCode.

Added a comment indicating where you can handle resolvable errors if needed.

Make sure to replace the TEST_SIM_PROFILE value with the appropriate activation code for your eSIM profile.

Comment: No need to use broadcast receivers as mentioned in the official docs?